# Raise keyboard layout change window/notification upon left Alt+Shift?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, notification

In Ubuntu 18.04, if I click <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, (where <kbd>Super</kbd> can be a key marked with Windows logo), I can change keyboard layouts, which is followed with a window overlay or notification (or whatever you wanna call it), which looks like this:

[image: kbd]

As leftover from my Windows days, I also mapped <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to change keyboard layout - which it does, however without raising the above window/notification.

Is there a way to set up Gnome3, so that this keyboard layout window/notification is also raised when I hit <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two ways to do it. You should probably first disable the <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> shortcut the way you activated it (assuming you used Tweaks).

Next go to *Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard -> Typing*. From there you can **change** the shortcuts for the built-in way to do it - with the overlay - rather than adding a new shortcut.

Comment: Many thanks, @GunnarHjalmarsson - indeed, it seems I had used Gnome Tweaks to set the shortcut ("Additional layout options"). Instead of "Typing", I see Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts, and then have to scroll down to see Typing category. I was about to ask - can I keep both Alt+Shift and Super+Space shortcuts, but there are two there: previous and next layout, so for next I can use alt+shift, for previous I can keep Super+Space. Except, I get a "Set Shortcut" window asking me to press key combo, and it doesn't detect alt+shift - any workarounds?

Comment: @sdaau: Hmm.. You are right - it doesn't accept only <Alt>+<Shift>. Then my answer is not very good. And no, I don't know how you would work around that limitation. Only thing I can say, then, is that you can have both - just as you have already - but without the overlay for <Alt>+<Shift>. If the overlay is important (why is that, btw?), then try to get used to <Super>+<Space> or some other combination which it does accept.

Answer (score 0):

- **Easy but bit laggy**:
  Use gnome-tweaks  ([install](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/gnome/gnome-tweaks.html)), under Keyboard and Mouse, Click Additional Layout Options, and you can enable Alt_shift.
  However using this made alt key "too sticky" for me, and on fast alt+shift click it would popup a menu as if you clicked only alt.  [and since i'd be typing, it would also result in some unwanted action]

**Works better, breaks backwards switch, which is irrelevant for only 2 input sources**:

1. Use gsettings to set the switch-keyboard-source shortcut in settings to alt+shift. 
   You have to choose a side for alt or shift for this to work. Fine with me as a I almost only use left shift for this.
   Examples; Choose one that suit you:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_R']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Shift>Alt_R']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Shift>Alt_L']"
```

2. Use gsettings / settings gui to set switch-keyboard-input-backward to Super+Space

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source-backwards "['<Super>Space']"
```

Works great for me.